# one view controller with multiple views

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

I've been confused for a long time. Say I have a view controller,when I tapped some button,the current View switch to another view,can I config different view's layout in one view controller in storyboard? Or is there a standard way to handle multiple views in one view controller? Really appreciate for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean UIView and not UIViewController (which would require the use of a ContainerView), then you can just work with the views [.hidden](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden) property like so:

```
    func switchViews ()
{
      if view1.hidden == true  && view2.hidden == false 
      {
        view1.hidden = false
        view2.hidden = true
      } 
      else 
      {
        view1.hidden = true
        view2.hidden = false
      }
}
```

You would just configure the views as you would normally

Comment: It's a way, appreciate for your response

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code :-

```
//You need to create a array of view's which you want to show along with a unique tag value:-

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.tag = 1;
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view2.tag = 2;
UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view3.tag = 3;

NSArray *viewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:view1,view2,view3, nil];

//In below method, you could pass the tag value of view which you want to show as argument.
- (void)addSubviewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag {

  for (int i=0;i <viewArray.count;i++){    //This loop will check and remove all view from self(parent view) which are not be to present or added.
    if([viewArray objectAtIndex:i].tag != tag){
        [[viewArray objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else{
        [self.view addSubview:[viewArray objectAtIndex:i]];  //The one which match's will be added as subview to self(parent view)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go for Apple standard layout guide.

1) You can use `UIScrollView` to manage subviews in it. And add scrollview to your view controller

2) `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` both are better than others when you want to manage complex views. Like delete, reorder and handle subviews event. Here you can get index of cell and subsequent subview detail